# Why after the openCV grayscale process, the channel disappered?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

I think the question might be super easy for some people, for me.. I can't figure it out,

Should it be 1 channel after processing like BGR2GRAY function?

```py
src = cv.imread("face.jpg", 0)
print(src.shape)

>>>(625, 616)
```

Comment: what do you mean? Conceptually `(625,616)` is equivalent to `(625,616,1)` or even `(625,616,1,1,1,1,1,1)`. So having lists/arrays for each pixel that only ever contain one element would be silly

Comment: Yes. You take a fraction of the red, a fraction of the green and a fraction of the blue to make a single channel (mono) that corresponds to brightness on a scale of black to white, i.e. greyscale.

Comment: @PeterT If you don't mind. Could you please briefly describe what do you mean by "(625, 616) = (625, 616, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1) " ?  so confused...

Comment: if you have e.g. 4*4 elements in a picture you can always say it's 4*4*1*1*1*1. You don't increase the amount of elements and saving it as [[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4]] seems better than [ [ [[[1]]], [[[2]]] , [[[3]]] , [[[4]]], [ [[[1]]], [[[2]]] , [[[3]]] , [[[4]]], [ [[[1]]], [[[2]]] , [[[3]]] , [[[4]]], [ [[[1]]], [[[2]]] , [[[3]]] , [[[4]]]] since you're not storing any additional information